# Winterbash page size doesn't match up with image locations

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ipad, winter-bash-2015

The Winterbash page using Chrome on iPad with iOS 9.2 does something weird with positioning images. That last house on the right:

[image]

This happens in portrait and landscape.

**Post fix being pushed** - here is the new layout:

[image]

Comment: I can't repro..

Comment: chrome on iPad. Latest versions of both. No plugins or extensions/blockers etc

Comment: Weird. It looks fine to me.

Comment: And if you rotate your screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for the catch. We pushed a fix. Please let me know if you still see any issues.

Comment: Thanks Kurtis - interestingly, the size is still slightly wrong - I'll pop a new screenshot up into the question post.

Comment: @RoryAlsop weird. Investigating.

Comment: @RoryAlsop should be fixed now.

Comment: Sorry for giving you extra work :-) status completed now